# Expected Value of a Carnival Game Paradox

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

I was in my Algebra 2 class today, and we're learning basic probability. Talking with my friend, he proposed this carnival game. The game begins with two dollars in the bowl, and every turn you flip a coin. If the result is heads, the carnival doubles the money in the bowl, and if tails, you take the money out of the bowl. The question is, what is the [expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) you would get from this game?

Starting from the first flip, you have a $1/2$ chance of getting 2 dollars. Multiplying these together, you get 1. Measuring the next flip, you have a $1/4$ change of getting 4 dollars, which multiply to 1 as well. Continuing this, you end up with the infinite sequence $1 + 1 + 1 + 1...$

How is this possible? Would you really statistically pay infinite money to play a game where you have a chance $50$% chance of getting $2?

Comment: This seems relevant: math.stackexchange.com/questions/495053/st-petersburg-paradox

Comment: Real life is actually worse than the St. Petersburg paradox.  Recall that "80% of everything is bad".  But if you don't play, you die, much much sooner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox), and there are many proposed methods to resolve it.

One is that the carnival worker doesn't have infinite money, and if you truncate the payout at a given point the expected value falls dramatically (as the logarithm of the carny's money).  Another is that if you think of it in terms of the *usefulness* you get out of the money, this is not simply a linear function of how much money you get. The difference between \$1 and \$2 prizes is "larger", in terms of what you can do with it, than the difference between a \$1,000,001 and a \$1,000,002 prize.